# C# Ensure no duplicates in byte array

Tags: c#, network-programming, arrays

What is the easiest way to ensure there are no duplicates and a byte array is in order, say from a network connection?

Comment: What do you mean when you say not duplicates? you don't what the same byte value to appear tiwce in the array? and by being in order do you mean sorted?

Comment: Which order? The order that you sent it? TCP (lower on the stack) has a built in error detection system that will ensure that the data you send (unless deliberately tampered with by a third party) will arrive at the destination: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Error_detection

Answer (score 3):

If you're on .NET 3.5, it's pretty easy to get unique items ...

```
var ba = new byte[6];

ba[0] = 1;
ba[1] = 1;
ba[2] = 2;
ba[2] = 2;
ba[3] = 3;
ba[4] = 4;
ba[5] = 4;

var res = ba.Distinct().ToArray();  // unique
```

Can you explain what you mean by "in order"?

Answer (score 2):

create an array of 256 booleans and iterate over the byte array one by one.

set each value in the array to true when you encounter it. if you encounter an already true value then the byte array is in an invalid format

I don't quite follow what you mean by the "byte array is in order" bit

You could also use a bitarray

example:

```
bool CheckForDuplicates(byte[] arr)
    {
        bool[] map = new bool[256];

        foreach (byte b in arr)
        {
            if (map[b] == true)
                return false;
            map[b] = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: + 1, but the if (map[b] == true) should really just be if (map[b]).  Personal preference I guess.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't what to throw an exception or such if the same value is encountered twice you could do:

```
var set = new HashSet<byte>(byteArray);
```

if you by being in order mean sorted you can call the LINQ extension method Sort on the object set from above